# Converting to float for division and then convert back

Tags: python, type-conversion

I am looking for a way to convert strings to a float for a division and then convert back to strings afterwards.

Strings;

```
scalavars.ExchangeValue
scalavars.Rate
```

int:

```
scalavars.CurrencyAmount
```

All contain values and I am trying to complete this equation;

```
scalavars.ExchangeValue = scalavars.CurrencyAmount / scalavars.Rate
```

How can I convert all three to floats for the division and then convert back to their orignal types and store the result in `scalavars.ExchangeValue` as a string again?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
scalavars.ExchangeValue = str(float(scalavars.CurrencyAmount) / float(scalavars.Rate))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Any way to round it to 2 decimal places in the same line?

Comment: Got it, never mind - `scalavars.ExchangeValue = str(round(float(scalavars.CurrencyAmount) / float(scalavars.Rate), 2))`